# Fastest way to check if two integers are on the same side of 0

Tags: java, performance, xor

I need to check if two integers are on the same side of zero many times. I don't care if it's positive or negative, just that it's the same side... and performance is very important.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
if (int1 == 0 || int2 == 0) {
    // handle zero
} else if ((int1 ^ int2) > 0) {
    // different side
} else {
    // same side
}
```

This is a 30% improvement in speed (tested with [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/)) over the more obvious:

```
if ((int1 > 0 && int2 > 0) || (int1 < 0 && int2 < 0)) {
```

Can it be done faster?

[If anyone wants to see the test framework I'm using for the 30%, it's here. I used caliper 0.5-rc1](http://pastebin.com/rqgdYFij)

**NOTE:** All of these solutions check the first bit, basically, which for zero is the same as a positive number. So if that works for your application, you don't need to do a zero check.

Benchmark list:

- **XOR:** Original answer with bugfix
- **Ifs:** Obvious `((&&)||(&&))` solution
- **Bits:** @hatchet's solution `(>>31) == (>>31)`
- **BitAndXor:** @greedybuddha's solution `(0x80000000)`
- **BitAndEquals:** @greedybuddha's solution modified to use `==` not `^`
- **XorShift:** @aaronman's solution `(^)>>31 == 0`

#### Caliper output:

```
0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=XOR} 1372.83 ns; ?=7.16 ns @ 3 trials
17% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Ifs} 2397.32 ns; ?=16.81 ns @ 3 trials
33% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Bits} 1311.75 ns; ?=3.04 ns @ 3 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=XorShift} 1231.24 ns; ?=12.11 ns @ 5 trials
67% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=BitAndXor} 1446.60 ns; ?=2.28 ns @ 3 trials
83% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=BitAndEquals} 1492.37 ns; ?=14.62 ns @ 3 trials

  benchmark   us linear runtime
        XOR 1.37 =================
        Ifs 2.40 ==============================
       Bits 1.31 ================
   XorShift 1.23 ===============
  BitAndXor 1.45 ==================
BitAndEquals 1.49 ==================

vm: java
trial: 0
```

Looks like @aaronman is the winner

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you checking the speed? Also, I would recommend not putting the zero case first, as it is presumably the least likely.

Comment: @Dgrin91 Ahead of you, I was editing that in :)

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `(int1 ^ int2) < 0` for the same sign?

Comment: @jlordo Sorry that was a typo

Comment: maybe Math.signum(a)?
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988805/fastest-way-to-get-sign-in-java

Comment: `(int1 ^ int2) < 0` uses 2 operations which can be handled directly by hardware. It doesn't go any quicker than that.

Comment: I bow to your brilliant question, it should be tagged as "answer trap". Everyone took a stab at this question seems to be getting downvoted. Perhaps yours is the one solution?

Comment: does this work for int1 == int2?

Comment: How about >>31 both values and compare with ==? You're adding a bitwise operation, but avoiding > or <.

Comment: @hatchet That answer runs in exactly the same time as XOR. But it would be the best answer so far, I'd checkmark it if there are no better answers.

Comment: Note: `(int1 ^ int2) < 0` checks that one number is negative, and the other nonnegative. You mixed that up in the question. Other note: I don't think you have a chance of beating that check. If you could get rid of the 0 check, if 0 could be handled as either positive or negative, as is more convenient, that would speed things up.

Comment: The difference between the top three solutions is small enough, and so dependent on just a few operations, that you might consider the possibility that the rank might be different, depending on the CPU model (if your development machine is different than the target machine). In other words, the difference between your original solution and the two better ones may well be "within the noise".

Comment: @hatchet don't be a sore loser, I doubt the CPU matters much since this is java, if you want to make the claim that the results are noise test in C and give us the results

Comment: @hatchet also ur solution is pretty clever so I upvoted  you anyway

Comment: @aaronman - I didn't want it to look like a sore loser comment (I upvoted your answer when I saw it - I like it better than mine). But yours is faster because of minor differences in either (or both) the speed of ^ vs. >>, and x==0 vs. x==y. Those minor differences may not be universal, or at least measurably different everywhere. I don't know...maybe they are.

Comment: @hatchet, sorry I was just kidding, the only reason I would say mine is actually faster is because in c I can just get rid of the `==` whereas in your solution you cannot do that

Comment: @aaronman I wonder if it makes sense to replace all `> 0` with `>> 31 == 0` everywhere in all code. Obviously you couldn't do it for `>` not-zero, but it still might work

Comment: @durron597 well I wouldn't expect java to do that but I wouldn't be suprised if a c++ compiler does something like that

Comment: Add `Integer.isPositive(int num)` to the api, haha

Comment: In case someone is tempted to assume the relative performance of these various techniques applies to other languages as well...don't. For example the speed rank of the top three answers here is the opposite in C#. x^y>0 is fastest, x>>31==y>>31 is second, and x^y>>31==0 is third. Which one is fastest depends on the language/compiler and the optimizations it makes under the covers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`(int1 ^ int2) >> 31 == 0 ? /*on same side*/ : /*different side*/ ;`  This doesn't necessarily handle 0 correctly I'm not sure what you wanted to do in that case.
EDIT: also wanted to point out that if this was in c instead of java, it could be optimized further by getting rid of the `== 0` because of the way that booleans work in c, the cases would be switched though

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the fastest answer. I plan to checkmark it a little later on unless someone comes up with something better.

Comment: Then someone should give me a cookie

Comment: I like the way your bits shift ;)

Comment: Why shift at all? (int1 ^ int2) >= 0 ? same : different should yield the exact same result

Comment: @Durandal i was thinking in c my answer where u could just get rid of == but if you want check the speeds urself i did no testing just answered the question

Answer (score 2):

```
if (int1 == 0 || int2 == 0) {
    // handle zero
} else if ((int1 >> 31) == (int2 >> 31)) {
    // same side
} else {
    // different side
}
```

or

```
if (int1 == 0 || int2 == 0) {
    // handle zero
} else if ((int1 & Integer.MIN_VALUE) == (int2 & Integer.MIN_VALUE)) {
    // same side
} else {
    // different side
}
```

The idea of both is the same - strip all but the sign bit, and then compare that for equality. I'm not sure which is faster, the right shift (>>) or the bitwise and (&).

Comment: @durron597 - I've put the bitwise and version back in.

Comment: The second answer is the same as @greedybuddha's answer, er, no it isn't, but I already changed his to that haha. Big edit coming up.

Comment: Can't cast `int` to a `bool`, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I would bitcast them to unsigned int, and xor the MSB (most-significant-bit) - much faster than any comparison (which does a subtraction) or multiplication

Comment: the concept remains though, i'm no java expert but i'm fairly sure you can do something like: (int1 & 0x8000000000000000L) ^ (int2 & 0x8000000000000000L) , give or take syntax issues and based on your integer size of course. It's mentioned here as well - [Best way to convert a signed integer to an unsigned long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578639/best-way-to-convert-a-signed-integer-to-an-unsigned-long)

Comment: There are no unsigned ints in Java

Comment: ok, so aside from casting, how is this different than what was suggested above? switching the brackets and saying (int1 ^ int2) & 0x8000000000000000 is quite the same as (int1 ^ int2) >> 31. I call dibs :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternate answers

Compare the sign bit

```
return ((n >> 31) ^ (n2 >> 31) ) == 0 ? /* same */ : /* different */;
```

Alternate way of comparing sign bit

```
return (((int1 & 0x80000000) ^ (int2 & 0x80000000))) == 0 ? /* same */ : /* different */;
```

and I just verified but Op's code is wrong when `int1 == int2`.  The following will always print different if they are the same.

```
if (int1 == 0 || int2 == 0) {
    // handle zero
} else if ((int1 ^ int2) < 0) {
    // same side
} else {
    // different side
}
```

Comment: But that's just the solution OP had.

Comment: alternate answer that I believe should be fast and correct. Which I've now seen that Ops code is not

Comment: Okay it should be `<=` or do `> 0` -> different side first

Comment: True, but that will slow it down a bit, how do my answers compare on your benchmark?

Comment: Mine I, believe is faster cause I only use right shift once whereas you do it twice, I changed yours

Comment: mine also deals with 0 though :).  I'd like to actually test, but I'm having issues getting caliper running

Comment: @greedybuddha caliper 1.0-beta doesn't work on Windows as far as I can tell. I fought with it for an hour before I went back to [0.5-rc1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.caliper|caliper|0.5-rc1|jar)

Comment: I got it working after like 10 minutes after I posted this.  I was thrown off by you using 0.5, which had different classes than 1.0.  but it's all good now :) thanks for introducing me to a good profiling system!

Answer (score 0):

Another answer...

```
final int i = int1 ^ int2;

if (i == 0 && int1 == 0) {
    // both are zero
} else if (i & Integer.MIN_VALUE == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    // signs differ
} else {
    // same sign
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
 int int1    = 3;
 int int2    = 4;
 boolean res = ( (int1 * int2) >= 0) ? true : false;

 System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem though, you need to know which one it is - zero or same side

Comment: Performance aside, this doesn't always work. See [http://ideone.com/2QkTyK](http://ideone.com/2QkTyK)

Comment: Now try: `int int1 = 1200000000; int int2 = 1500000000;`