# Fastest Two Number Sign Comparison Including Zero

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, sign, zero

What is the fastest way to find if two numbers have the same sign considering that the sign can either be positive, negative or zero.

Commonly, you can say two numbers have same signs with this:

```
Math.signum(int1) == Math.signum(int2);
```

You can optimize this by using this:

```
int1 ^ int2 >= 0;
```

however, this is making the assumption that zero is positive. What are some ways that will return true including zero.

Some examples of errors would be:

```
a = 0; b = 1;
boolean test = a ^ b >= 0
```

where test would yield true instead of false.

I ran some testbenchs and found that the bitwise function returns values faster by nearly 4 orders of magnitude. Since this is a function I will be using in a very large tree for every node, I need to optimize this as much as possible.

I would post an attempted solution, but I can't find one that beats the original one.

Edit: I realize there is a similar problem found here: [Fastest way to check if two integers are on the same side of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950163/fastest-way-to-check-if-two-integers-are-on-the-same-side-of-0)
I am asking if there is a way to find if signs are the same INCLUDING zero. so comparisons between 1 and 1 is true, -1 and -1 is true, 0 and 0 is true, 0 and 1 is false, 0 and -1 is false, etc. This is not the same thing as the question asked above!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if two integers are on the same side of 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950163/fastest-way-to-check-if-two-integers-are-on-the-same-side-of-0)

Comment: Let it go.  You cannot be interested in efficiency and choose to develop in java.  For efficiency, choose a language like either assembler, c, or (perhaps) fortran

Comment: Here is answer for question I've linked above: `(int1 ^ int2) >> 31 == 0 ? /*on same side*/ : /*different side*/ `

Comment: @Andremoniy I already checked this solution. This does not handle the case for zero as I mentioned in the title.

Comment: @DwB, we're not in 1996 anymore.

Comment: With compiler optimisation and CPU optimisation, what appears to be on paper the faster solution may not end up being such in practice.

Comment: Does it have to work for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: @AntonH I ran a test bench of 100,000 comparisions between the two operations and the bitwise operation significantly performed better (by 1000x fold). Obviously if I were to include the zero case, it would not be so great but I wanted to try. I decided to try and optimize this comparison since this was a hotspot for the most runtime in a particular function.

Comment: @harold no. This only has to work for very small numbers (-8 to 8)

Comment: @DwB do you know of a way to accomplish this goal in c or c++? this problem is not strictly for java, though it would be convenient.

Comment: I suspect it will be a variation of this:  ((char1 ^ char2) & 0x80) == 0  adjust the 0x80 for the size of the actual xor values.  specifically, bitwise xor the values then mask off every bit except the sign bit.  This is not sufficient if you can have positive-zero and negative-zero values and you want to consider positive-zero equal to negative zero.  I assume that the straight mask is faster than a 31 bit shit.  Not sure and it may depend on hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
private static boolean signcmp(int x, int y) {
    return ((( x >> 31) | (-x >>> 31)) ^ (( y >> 31) | (-y >>> 31))) == 0; 
}
```

Comment: `(a ^ b) == 0` is the same thing as `a == b`, I hope the JIT compiler knows that too, but it might still be nicer idk

Comment: And I must say I'm really surprised the difference is that big, they're really just minor variants of each other. OR vs SUB, SHR vs SAR, it shouldn't really matter

Comment: @harold its probably because you gave a part of the solution and I didn't implement it well enough. The largest difference I can see is the OR vs SUB. do they really take the same amount of time?

Comment: @MichaelChoi they're equally fast on any machine I know about, in hardware OR is faster of course but you're not writing VHDL here. Perhaps you timed them unreliably? You could try if switching the order of the benchmarks makes a difference for example.

Comment: @harold yeah I just tried switching the order which had inconsistent results. I am not really that great at coding yet so I think my test benches were not as accurate. Running them alone yields nearly identical results and I am assuming deviations are simply a result of background tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an integer version of `signum`, such as (not tested):

```
int signum(int x) {
    int m = x >> 31;
    int neg_m = -x >> 31;
    return m - neg_m;
}
```

Here `m` will be -1 iff `x < 0` (0 otherwise), and `neg_m` will be -1 iff `x > 0` (ignoring Integer.MIN_VALUE). Their difference is,

- -1, for x < 0
- 0, for x == 0
- 1, for x > 0

It also gives 0 for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, but since that never occurs in your case that shouldn't matter.

Comment: similar answer can be found @Matthew_McPeak This is chosen as the answer due to better clarity.

Comment: Also, I believe my answer works for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, due to use of unsigned right shift on the negative values, not that it matters for the OP.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak thanks to the OR-logic, I'd say, but that's enabled by the unsigned shift so it's sort of back to that.. For example the unsigned shift together with addition would be exactly equivalent to what I came up with

Answer (score 0):

Without having benchmarked this, I doubt whether you could do any better than

```
sameSign = a < 0 ? b < 0 : ( a == 0 ) == ( b == 0 );
```

Comment: I ran a testbench at it appears it runs slower than @harold's solution. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  Thanks for checking.  You may find it's hardware dependent, but I doubt it.